# Alertify - Show success message with delay

Tags: jquery, alertify

```
if(jQuery("#form_fill_hours").validationEngine('validate')){

    alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this exam form to your teacher?", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        alertify.set({ delay: 10000 });
        alertify.success("Your exam form has been submitted");
        $.blockUI.defaults.message = "<h1 class='block_msg'>Please Wait...</h1>";
        $.post( SITE_URL+"fill/save/saveformexam?type=1",$("#form_fill_hours").serialize(), function( data ) {
            window.location.href="<?php echo EXAM_URL."exam/weekly/index?week=".$_GET['week'] ?>";
        });
    } else {
        alertify.error("Your exam form is not submitted");
    }
});
            return false;
    }else{
            return false;
    }
```

Using alertify, I have set `10` secs delay for the success message but it is not working? I just need to show success alert to user and then
redirect to same page.

Tried using `delay` but not working though:

```
alertify.success("Your exam form has been submitted");//show alert to user
delay(100);//wait for 10 secs and then post form data
$.post( SITE_URL+"fill/save/saveformexam?type=1",$("#form_fill_hours").serialize(), function( data ) {
                window.location.href="<?php echo EXAM_URL."exam/weekly/index?week=".$_GET['week'] ?>";
            });
```

How could I set some delay in success message so that user can see it and only then post the form details to controller action ?

Comment: you want to show the message after 10 sec?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, alert should be shown for 10 secs and only then it should `$.post` the form data

Comment: is there a delay before the success message is shown ?

Comment: settimeout seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/5HygY/62/

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla sorry for typo. I have used delay where alert message will be shown and then form data  will be posted to controller action. Please see my updated question

Comment: what is delay? I have not heard of it before. Is it a custom function ? or a standard function?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, pls see this - https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) is used only between jQuery effects. Here is what the docs say

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So the only way to create a delay before post method is settimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $.post( SITE_URL+"fill/save/saveformexam?type=1",$("#form_fill_hours").serialize(), function( data ) {
    window.location.href="<?php echo EXAM_URL."exam/weekly/index?week=".$_GET['week'] ?>";
  });
}, 1000);
```